# HttpUrlConnection Keep Alive doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, keep-alive

I set up an [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) and set the system properties for a single keep alive connection per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html):

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "true");
System.setProperty("http.maxConnections", "1");
```

Android simply ignores these. I'm seeing connections on multiple ports at the same IP for http traffic in wireshark. Am I missing something or is this just broken on  Android? I've tried on Android-L and also Android-M preview, it's broken on both.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Android do you use, in some versions of Android, there is a bug about socket reuse, please refer to the following links.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38817
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=43132#makechanges

and maybe you can try to remove the gzip content type to avoid the bug.

Comment: Also, we're not using gzip but I do see `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` in the header.

Comment: I suggest turn off the chunked encoding and have a test, chunked can also cause the problem according to the two links.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry we are experiencing a similar bug - did you ever find if turning off chunked encoding solved the problem?